# Office 2016 activation issue after migration to a new computer

Tags: ms-office, keychain, migration

After migrating to a new computer when trying to active Office 2016 I'm getting the following error message:

> Another account from the same organization is already signed in. To
>   switch accounts, please go to Applications/Utilities/Keychain access,
>   clear all entries including the 'Office' keyword, and then restart the
>   app.

I tried following the steps here https://medium.com/@wangyidan621/microsoft-office-activation-and-keychain-removal-19664b1e7e77 but it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working was going to https://portal.office.com/account/ then Install Status, deactivating the license, and then signing in and activating the application (e.g. Word) again.